# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: & Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity:

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have created two entity classes.

RoleEntity:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table (name ="roles")
public class RoleEntity {

@Id
@Column(name = "role_id")
private Integer roleId;
@Column(name = "role_name")
private String roleName;
//Getters
//Setters
```

UserEntity:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="user_master")
public class UserEntity {

@Id
private Integer id;
@Column(name = "user_name")
private String username;
@Column(name = "user_password")
private String password;
//getters
//setters
```

Now i have a simple pojo which will take data from these two entities and later will be used in a service.

```
import java.util.Set;

public class UserRoleAssociationEntity {

UserEntity user;
Set<RoleEntity> roles;
//getters
//setters
```

Now I am getting error when I run the project.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.dataGuru.BusDirV3.Entities.UserRoleAssociationEntity
```

If I annotate the UserRoleAssociationEntity class with @entity i get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.dataGuru.BusDirV3.Entities.UserRoleAssociationEntity
```

What is the problem which i am facing here & solution for this problem.

Comment: I think jpa will create an association table for you if you have a property of `Set<RoleEntity>` in the `UserEntity`

Comment: that will be the case if i annotate it with @entity, but when i don't use any annotation it should work as a simple pojo. but that is'nt happening here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a unique field in your class which acts as an identifier for this entity. (Field with `@Id` annotation`)

Comment: in that case it will throw an error for UserEntity user; and Set<RoleEntity> roles; as unidentified type. I simply want to use this class as a pojo.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of creating a new POJO, add a many-to-many relation ship in the UserEntity Class like.

```
 import javax.persistence.Column;
 import javax.persistence.Entity;
 import javax.persistence.Id;
 import javax.persistence.Table;

 @Entity
 @Table(name="user_master")
 public class UserEntity 
{
 @Id
 private Integer id;
 @Column(name = "user_name")
 private String username;
 @Column(name = "user_password")
 private String password;
 @Column(name = "user_password")
 private String password;

 @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER) //
 @JoinTable(
        name="USERROLE_ASSOCIATION",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")})
private Set<RoleEntity> UserRoleAssociationEntity ;
```

Comment: It seems logical and did it too. I added one to one relation for userEntity in UserRoleAssociation as in database userRoleassociation table contains foreign keys for user_id and Role_id. but still no progress same error persists. ;(

Comment: add many to many, and have you deleted this UserRoleAssociationEntity  class from your package.

Comment: You don't need that POJO any more, you can get the desired data from userEntity.getUserRoleAssociationEntity(); you will get all the roles associated with the user. You dont need a seperate POJO